Issue with QFieldSync update as of 2024-09-13 on QGIS 3.34.8
I am working on a project built on QGIS 3.34.8. When I try to export the project for QFieldSync, I receive the following Python code error:
WARNING    warning:C:\Users\inbox\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qfieldsync\libqfieldsync.whl\libqfieldsync\offline_converter.py:347: DeprecationWarning: QgsProject.setAutoTransaction() is deprecated
              project.setAutoTransaction(False)

 traceback: File "C:\Users/inbox/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\gui\package_dialog.py", line 191, in package_project
              offline_convertor.convert()
              File "C:\Users\inbox\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qfieldsync\libqfieldsync.whl\libqfieldsync\offline_converter.py", line 141, in convert
              self._convert(project)
              File "C:\Users\inbox\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qfieldsync\libqfieldsync.whl\libqfieldsync\offline_converter.py", line 334, in _convert
              self.post_process_offline_layers()
              File "C:\Users\inbox\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qfieldsync\libqfieldsync.whl\libqfieldsync\offline_converter.py", line 347, in post_process_offline_layers
              project.setAutoTransaction(False)

I am using the cable export to put the project on the phone on QField and when I do this, the layers are not recognized by the qgis project file.
From the export folder, the QGIS Project opens fine on QGIS.
I don't speak Python but I am hoping someone might be able to interpret this for me.
